# Run-in with an odd use of kanji 「供膳」

Tags: translation, meaning, kanji, song-lyrics

I'm currently working on a translation of a song ("故" by Gremlins) and I have run into something quite strange... While it is not unusual for Japanese lyricists to use kanji with a different meaning than what their singing suggests, or otherwise be creative with their lyrics, I cannot find a connection here, or even understand why he would use these kanji together.

The lyrics goes like this:

愛が故、枯れる花弁。

哀しき月明かり。

息を沈め、空溶かし、今艶を求む。

降り注ぐ優しき愛で、

あなたを愛憎しむ。

亡きを見つめ、飛び続け、尚、**供膳を望む**

羽ばたいて。

I am almost a hundred percent certain what he says is 'kuzen wo nozomu' but while the reading makes sense, I don't actually know what it would mean? Nozomu looks sligtly different to me too, but that could be the small font in the pamphlet, I am not sure. I haven't been able to find the kanji I see it as anywhere...

Does anyone have any suggestions? The theme is very traditional, so there could be some classical or outdated kanji use involved, but I have no clue.

Comment: Did you try looking up 供膳 in a dictionary or in google?

Comment: I have tried every online dictionary I know and google, too, of course. I don't have my actual dictionaries with me here, so I haven't been able to look through them, but it doesn't really seem like this combination is used at all...

Answer (score 4):

I found it [here](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BE%9B%E8%86%B3%E3%81%AE%E5%84%80).

It appears to be a very formal word describing when two newlyweds have their first meal together.

Given the lyrical content, though, it may be referring to [this](http://www.e-butsudan.com/02_ryouguzen.html). 供膳 in this sense refers to a ritual where food is left for deceased ancestors. If the person singing is staring down death, this may be what it is.

[image: 供膳]

I am not *totally* sure either way, though. This is just what I found with some quick searching!